# i am facing error while compiling the source code in apache

Tags: apache

Below is the error while running make command

```
/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2 -pthread    \
      -L/opt/httpd/expat/lib   -o ab  ab.lo      /home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/srclib/apr-util/libaprutil-1.la -lexpat /home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/srclib/apr/libapr-1.la -luuid -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lm -lssl -lcrypto -luuid -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl
ab.o: In function `ssl_state_cb':
/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/support/ab.c:575: undefined reference to `SSL_in_init'
ab.o: In function `ssl_print_cert_info':
/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/support/ab.c:653: undefined reference to `X509_get_version'
/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/support/ab.c:655: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notBefore'
/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/support/ab.c:659: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notAfter'
ab.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ab.o: In function `sk_X509_value':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ab.o: In function `main':
/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/support/ab.c:2305: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/support/ab.c:2560: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/support/ab.c:2637: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/support/ab.c:2638: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/support/ab.c:2647: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
ab.o: In function `test':
/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/support/ab.c:1990: undefined reference to `SSL_in_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ab] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/support'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/apache/httpd-2.4.41/support'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Please let me know how to proceed further.
openssl version is OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem? I have the same trouble and have not been able to figure it out

Comment: @bio_sprite have a look at my answer :) maybe it could fix it. Or, download from another mirror.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is because of OpenSSL. To solve this try the following:

This cleans all the compilation previously done, so might remove problem

```
make clean
```

If that does not work, download Apache from http://apachemirror.wuchna.com/httpd/httpd-2.4.41.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Download OpenSSL and compile to a different directory.

> ./config --prefix=/u01/openssl1.1.1k/

compile apache with --with-ssl directives

> -with-ssl=/u01/openssl1.1.1k/